# Store listing plugin for Joomla?

Tags: plugins, joomla

I need a plugin for Joomla what simply lists out different stores under each other (imagine as a table where each row is a store with some details.) The difficult part is that I need them to be filterable for cities.

eg. if the visitor selects "New York", the plugin displays only the stores located in new york.

Do you know a plugin for this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use content  and add tags for each city or use com_contact and do filtering in contact or use  a smart search map or use tags again.